# overflow-x scroll not working

Tags: html, css

i have 2 files, x-scroll.html & scroll_table.html, need to use iframe to include another one. i need the horizontal scroll bar after the footer, instead of before the footer. 
Appreciate your answers!!

x-scroll.html ==>

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scroll-x overflow test</title>
    <style>
        html, body{
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          overflow:hidden;
          margin:0px;   

        }

        div.content{
          width:100%;
          height:90%;
          overflow:hidden;
          margin:0px;   

        } 

        .footer{
            background-color: #ffffcc;
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">  

        <iframe name="main" src="scroll_table.html" width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Scroll bar test</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

scroll_table.html ==>
https://codepen.io/klim1167/pen/odNgLW

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The scroll bar will be in the end of div`container`.I suggest you wrap table to one div and make this scroll

```
<div class="wrap-table">
    <table id="single" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
    ...
    </table>
</div>

.wrap-table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGbzKW

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, Tan.